# Polymer: Applying animations to dom elements in dom-repeat template

Tags: javascript, animation, dom, polymer

By binding an array to a dom-repeat template in Polymer, you are able to dynamically create and destroy dom elements by pushing or splicing the bound array. I would like to be able to apply fade-in and fade-out animations to these elements as they are created and destroyed, similar to how the angularJS ngRepeat directive behaves.

Are there any simple methods for applying an animation to an element when it is created or destroyed by the dom-repeat template in Polymer?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of solves the "created" animation but still leaves you with some work to do for the "destroyed" animation.

I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5mm6osj4/) with a small working example of the "created" animation but I'll still explain it here.

First of all, there's two elements, the first one is called `x-repeated` for simplicity and it's the one with the `dom-repeat` and the second one is called `x-animated` and that would represent any item of the `dom-repeat`.

The point of doing this is making it so that `x-animated` extends `NeonAnimationRunnerBehavior` so that it can run an animation on its `attached` callback to do the "created" animation.

Now, you might notice that the `x-animated` also runs an animation on its `detached` callback but it doesn't do anything, that's because the callback is called *after* it's been detached so it's no longer visible by the time the animation runs here.

So in order to do the "destroy" animation with this model you'd need to animate first and remove later, I guess you could do that by adding a method to the "repeater" element that lets you remove a given element of the array and you call a method in the "animated" element to run the animation before removing it.

The only other "simple" way I can think of doing this right now would be just plain doing both the adding/removing of items and the animations from the "repeater" element.

Someone else might have a better way to do this, but I don't really think there's a much simpler way of doing this right now.

**Update:**
The old fiddle no longer works but @Ali.MD provided [this updated version](https://jsfiddle.net/vxwzoj7m/1/) in case anyone wants to still check it out.

However, considering we now live in the Polymer 3.0/LitElement world, you should probably just use CSS animations by now.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was rather hoping that there was some simple method built into the library that I was overlooking on the documentation. The major problem with your approach (which may, in fact, be the only approach right now) is that because the 'destroyed' animation must run before changes to the model are made, changes to the model must either be delayed an arbitrary amount of time or be made in response to the 'neon-animation-finish' event. The issue I have been having with the latter option is that I tend to hear the event more often than I anticipate.

Comment: @alan-dávalos your sample code does not work anymore, please remind to define a specific version in polygit.org links. https://jsfiddle.net/vxwzoj7m/1/

Comment: @Ali.MD thanks, I'll update the post with a link to your fiddle